# Order sheets based on input in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

In the Excel spreadsheet the user can define the order of the sheets within **Column A**:

```
       A        B
1   Sheet3
2   Sheet4
3   Sheet1
4   Sheet2
5
```

Once the user enterred the order in **Column A** he/she can click a button which is linked to this VBA code:

```
Sub Move()
Sheets(Sheet1.Range("A2").Value).Move After:=Sheets(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value)
Sheets(Sheet1.Range("A3").Value).Move After:=Sheets(Sheet1.Range("A2").Value)
Sheets(Sheet1.Range("A4").Value).Move After:=Sheets(Sheet1.Range("A3").Value)
End Sub
```

This VBA puts the sheets in the order based on the inputs from the user in **Column A**. All this works fine so far

---

Now I have the issue that the number of sheets varies so it can happen that instead of only 4 sheets there will be 8 or 10 or 15 and so on. In this case it would be necessary to add all those sheets manually to the VBA code.

Is it possible to make the VBA code more dynamically. Something like an array for the values in **Column A** and a VBA like this:

```
Sub Move()
MoveSheets based on Array {Sheet1.Range("A1:A5")}
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work if your sheet names are on "Sheet1" in B4 going down.

```
Sub x()

Dim n As Long, i As Long, r As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set r = .Range("B4", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For n = r.Count To 1 Step -1
        Sheets(r.Cells(n).Value).Move after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count - i)
        i = i + 1
    Next n
    Application.Goto .Range("A1")
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome. Works perefectly. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to also make the starting point of the down going dynamically. For example if the input from the User is in range B4:B7?

Comment: You could add an input box at the beginning so the user selects the range.

Comment: I mean the range is still pre-defined but instead of A1:A4 it is B4:B7. I tried to change this part in your code: For n = .Range("B4" & Rows.Count). .... but I get runtime error 1001

Comment: Do you mean it always starts in B4 instead of A1?

Comment: Yes that is what i mean.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the additional help.